# Trouble Deploying FastAPI Project on Azure Functions or testing locally

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, fastapi

I'm working on a Python FastAPI project and I'm trying to deploy it using Azure Functions. I came across this repository [fastapi-on-azure-functions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/) which provides a guide on how to accomplish this.

While the documentation states that it's a simple example code, I couldn't Test it locally or deploy it to azure.

After creating a Python virtual environment and activating it. I installed the requirements as stated in the documentation. But when I run `func start`or `func host start`. I get a respond like the following.
[image]

and when I try to to deploy it to azure I don't have the `WrapperFunction` under `Local Project`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I was not able to see the functions or run the function locally:

[image]

***To make it work, create a new environment:***

[image]
[image]

Open Terminal, run `pip install requirements.txt`:

[image]

Run the function locally using the command `func host start`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pravallika, I was also not using Dev containers.