# Deployment of FastAPI Python Azure Function successful, but triggers not showing up

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, fastapi

I have been working on a FastAPI Python Azure Function project, and after completing the implementation and testing it locally, I attempted to deploy it to Azure. However, even though the deployment process indicates success, the trigger functions are not showing up, even tough it works fine when tested locally.
[image]

[image]

Is there something I'm missing

Comment: Try adding `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in the function app configuration setting and then redeploy [image](https://i.imgur.com/QWh1Jqa.png)

Comment: It has been set to ```True``` already. Do you have any another suggestions, I was looking for hours for solutions I would really appreciate it

Comment: can you try to deploy in this way [image](https://i.imgur.com/aUicrrL.png) or use cli command for deployment

Comment: @alexx087, I have deployed your application which I got from your previous [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842742/trouble-deploying-fastapi-project-on-azure-functions-or-testing-locally) question(which I answered). I could deploy the function project to  and run the deployed application. Refer [Image1](https://i.imgur.com/Sg5bdvY.png), [Image2](https://i.imgur.com/KKuOzZ5.png) , [Image 3](https://i.imgur.com/gb1Mlrd.png). Check the [application settings](https://i.imgur.com/lp2jlE8.png) of your Function App=>settings=>configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to deploy your [function app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/) which I got from your previous [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842742/trouble-deploying-fastapi-project-on-azure-functions-or-testing-locally) [*which I answered*], and I could deploy without any issues.

**Steps I followed to deploy:**

- Created a python linux function app with Consumption plan in Portal.

[image]

- **Application Settings of my function app:**

[image]

**To deploy function project to Azure:**

- Go to Visual Studio Code=> Click on Azure icon=> Click on Function icon=> Choose Deploy to Function App as shown below:

[image]

- Select your function app from the displayed list of function apps and click on ***Deploy***.

[image]
[image]

***Function App gets deployed successfully:***

[image]

Click on the URL `https://<functionapp>.azurewebsites.net//%7B*route%7D`.

**Response:**

[image]

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]